# Align checkbox labels (web)

Tags: html, css

A picture says more than a thousand words?

[image: screenshot]

I would like the second (and consecutive) lines to be aligned with the first. Any ideas?

Html is

```
<input><span>text</span>
```

Comment: Tried that. div causes the text to display below the checkbox. div with style="display:inline;" does the same as in the question

Comment: `inline-block` and wrapped inside a `span` works for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
.thing input { float: left; }
.thing label { display: block; margin-left: 2em; }

<div class="thing">
    <input type="radio" id="potato"/>
    <label for="potato">Text over multiple lines should be aligned properly...</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same things and solved it this way.  The big problem was checkbox list items whose text took up multiple lines.

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkboxlist">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="This is a checkbox option in an unordered list that is pretty long and ends u wrapping onto another line, but maintains alignment" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="This is yet another checkbox option in an unordered list that is pretty long and ends u wrapping onto another line, but maintains alignment" />
            <div>
                <br /> Here's some other info as well that isn't a part of the checkbox. The alignment for this works as well.
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.checkboxlist ul li { margin: 7px 0px; }
div.checkboxlist ul li input { width: 15px; display: block; float:left;}
div.checkboxlist ul li label { padding-left: 28px; display: block; }
div.checkboxlist ul li div { margin-left: 28px; clear: both; font-size: .9em; }
```

For a more detailed discussion see my post here:
[Aligning a List of Checkboxes with Text that Wraps](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/aligning-a-list-of-checkboxes-with-text-that-wraps/)